# why just after initializing the zram read is issued before write?

Tags: android, memory-management, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, block-device

I am newbie to Linux kernel and just started to know how `zram` works. Initial testing, I am seeing that `READ` is issued before `WRITE` just after the `zram` is being initialized. But I am just eager to know, **why this is so ?**

As an activity I took the `dump_stack()` and followed the path form where to how this `zram` read is being performed.

`zram` get to know this info whether it has to do `READ` or `WRITE` operation on issued `bio->bi_rw`. Code flow is like that `zram_make_request` API is being called from `create_device` in `zram` driver. And `zram_make_request` internally called `__zram_make_request` which called the `zram_bvec_rw` API.

In `zram_bvec_rw` API check the available info of `bio->bi_rw` and correspondingly issued the `READ` and `WRITE` call.

Now, in this case what is happening: `READ` is being encapsulated inside `bio` struct itself. As triage I found that `submit_bh` fills all the entry of `bio` and issued the `submit_bio`.

I was wondering who is actually sets the `bio->bi_rw` as `READ`. By enabling the few prints I found that `ll_rw_block` API is being called by `__block_write_begin` with `READ`, later `ll_rw_block` calls the `submit_bh` API where rest of `bio` struct entries are filled.

But I am still not getting the answer **why `READ` is issued for `ll_rw_block` from `__block_write_begin` ?**

- **zram driver:**

https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/drivers/block/zram/zram_drv.c?id=refs/tags/v3.18.14

in file: https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/fs/buffer.c?id=refs/tags/v3.18.14

```
    if (!buffer_uptodate(bh) && !buffer_delay(bh) &&
        !buffer_unwritten(bh) &&
         (block_start < from || block_end > to)) {
        ll_rw_block(READ, 1, &bh);
        *wait_bh++=bh;
    }



 buffer_uptodate(bh),   /* Contains valid data */
 buffer_delay(bh),  /* Buffer is not yet allocated on disk */
 buffer_unwritten(bh),  /* Buffer is allocated on disk but not written */
```

Please can someone give an explaination/answer to my question ?

**How I am concluding that read is perfomed before write ??**

I just check the `num_reads` and `num_writes` count. And `num_reads` count is set to `1` while `num_writes` is found `0` when we do `mkswap /dev/block/zram0` and after calling the `swapon /dev/block/zram0` the final counts are `num_reads = 2 and num_writes=1`.

**NOTE:** This is the case when we don't performing any additional `zram` activity. We got this behavior in case as explained above.

Answer (score -1):

Because of this as far as i can see: block_start < from || block_end > to (respecting other conditions of course, buffer_uptodate() etc.) .
i.e. bio will write a whole block so if a region to be updated smaller than submited block you obviously need a fresh copy.